# Disabling camera on Android (acer iconia a500)

Tags: android

Can someone tell me the location of drivers (specifically camera drivers) in Android System files? (I am working on an acer iconia a500) We have students using these and deleting the driver for the camera seems to me the best way to disable it. (please correct me if you have a better idea!)

Comment: These droids belong to students in class. They are not to be recording video or taking photos in class.

Comment: let your students enjoy the camera... gave them some freedom and enjoy.. this can increase their interest to learn more..:)

Comment: So recording classes for later study is out of the question? Or taking pictures of the chalkboard/whiteboard/projection for annotation? I use the Acer Iconia W500 and love using it's camera for legitimate classwork. It and One Note are a god-send.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not how it works. These are JH/HS students we have to limit distraction in class. And recording their teachers and posting it, or trying to find the 'gotcha' moment to make a teacher look back is not acceptable.

Comment: In college you can do that. Not Middle School or High School.

Comment: We have already had problems with this issue.

Comment: So teacher's aren't responsible for their actions?

Comment: Corey, I'm just the messenger and the one asking the question about location of drivers. Anyone know the answer?

Comment: And yes teachers are responsible for their actions, but we are trying to protect the teachers from 'edited' stuff that is out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I don't agree with why you're doing this...

There seem to be some important camera files in /system/lib/, files I see on my Optimus T (that should be present on any android device) are:

libcamera.so
libcamera_client.so
libcameraservice.so
liboemcamera.so

However I'm unsure if those were placed there in a legit version of Android or if they're just present in Cyanogenmod 6.3.

If you're going to do this, you'll need to root in order to access these files. They appear to be binary so it's not just a simple configuration change. Deleting would be a tricky solution, but might be a solution nonetheless.

Comment: Wait... it worked? ha ha, I didn't test it because I want my camera. Can you report back success or fail?